# Connection problems with PostgreSQL XADataSource in Glassfish

Tags: java, database, postgresql, glassfish

I'm new to GlassFish, and our company has recently migrated an old system from JBoss 2-something to GlassFish v3.  Almost everything works fine, but we are having connection problems with a PostGres (v8.1) XADataSource.  We have a database entry that holds the operating mode of the site and every request pulls this information to verify that they are requesting a valid page.

However, if multiple users attempt to do this, it fails.  This never occurred under JBoss running PostGres 7.2.  Here is the main offender:

```
sai.mbz.util.GeneralFailureException: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException: sai.mbz.dat.generic.GenericDAOException: Exception caught in DAO: java.lang.RuntimeException: Got exception during XAResource.end: org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: tried to call end without corresponding start call; nested exception is: 
    sai.mbz.util.GeneralFailureException: sai.mbz.dat.generic.GenericDAOException: Exception caught in DAO: java.lang.RuntimeException: Got exception during XAResource.end: org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: tried to call end without corresponding start call
    at sai.mbz.control.admin.AdminControllerWebImpl.getParmInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sai.mbz.control.web.RequestProcessor.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.Main_jsp._jspService(Main_jsp.java from :74)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:406)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:483)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Is there any chance that someone could help a newbie out?

Comment: Please update your question to include the **complete** stacktrace (including all root causes).

Comment: Offtopic: PostgreSQL version 8.1 will be EOL this year. You should start a migration. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Release_Support_Policy

Comment: Release policy has been moved to official site: http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 1):

The exception stack indicates that there is no XA transaction in active state when `XAResource.end` is called.

What is unclear is how do you manage transactions? And do you really need an XA data source? If you don't, I'd suggest to configure a non-XA (i.e resource-local) data source.